# System of equations TexShop Mac OS

Tags: equations

I wrote this code in TexShop (Mac OS):

```
h(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x & \mathrm{if} \;\; x \notin \mathcal{A}\bigcup\mathbb{N}\\ 
f(g(x))& \mathrm{if} \;\; x \in \mathcal{A}\bigcup\mathbb{N}
\end{matrix}\right.
```

and the software returns me this error:

> misplaced alignment tab character &

and even if I replace & with \; I found this:

[image]

How can I solve? I would like to see this:

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem (after inserted your code in math mode).

Comment: `\bigcup` is wrong and should be `\cup`. The former is for indexed unions, the difference is the same as between `+` and `\sum`.

Answer (score 3):

**Load `amsmath` package.**

I'd use `cases` like this: (also, `cup` instead of `bigcup`

```
\[
h(x)=\begin{cases}
x, & \text{if $x \notin \mathcal{A}\bigcup\mathbb{N}$,}\\ 
f(g(x)), & \text{if $x \in \mathcal{A}\bigcup\mathbb{N}$.}
\end{cases}
\]
```

Just to compare, here is your code, in math mode: (`\mathrm{}` is not for text)

```
\[
h(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x & \mathrm{if} \;\; x \notin \mathcal{A}\bigcup\mathbb{N}\\ 
f(g(x))& \mathrm{if} \;\; x \in \mathcal{A}\bigcup\mathbb{N}
\end{matrix}\right.
\]
```

[image]

Comment: If I use also \[ and \] TexShop returns: "Bad math environment delimiter".
If I write your code without \[ and \], it shows me the same thing (all in one line)...

Comment: @BiagioIanero, pay attention in the back slash `\[ \]`.

Comment: Load `amsmath`  package, also.

Comment: Yes, I also used the back slash.

Comment: Oh thank you! amsmath was the right thing to do!

Comment: Welcome. `amsmath` is like food, hard to live without it... :)